# Oracle composite primary key with CLOB data point

Tags: sql, oracle

How does one utilize the CLOB data type as part of a unique key in Oracle?

```
create table log_table
( message CLOB,
  id number,
 CONSTRAINT f PRIMARY KEY (message, id)
)
```

fails with:

> ORA-02329: column of datatype LOB cannot be unique or a primary key

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggestion:

You could pass your data into a hash function like `MD5` or another one.
The hashed value would be stored in `message_key` field.

```
create table log_table
( message_key VARCHAR2( 2048 ),
  message CLOB,
  id number,
 CONSTRAINT f PRIMARY KEY (message_key, id)
)
```

Comment: now that is an interesting approach.  So you are suggesting to hash the clob and use that as my composite key yes?